# How do I create an alias to a Python class through Swig?

Tags: python, templates, swig, alias, rename

I've created a C++ library and have successfully used swig to make it accessible through python.  Templating is used heavily in the library and each template type is mapped to its own python class by swig like so:

```
%template(Imageint) Image<int>;
%template(Imagedouble) Image<double>;
```

However, I would really like to have a 'default' template used by python such that

```
a = Image("filename")
```

instantiates `Image<double>` without having to always type

```
a = Imagedouble("filename")
```

Swig documentation states:

> The %template directive should not be
>   used to wrap the same template
>   instantiation more than once in the
>   same scope. This will generate an
>   error. This error is caused because
>   the template expansion results in two
>   identical classes with the same name.
>   This generates a symbol table
>   conflict. Besides, it probably more
>   efficient to only wrap a specific
>   instantiation only once in order to
>   reduce the potential for code bloat.

So to avoid the symbol table conflict, I tried

```
%rename(Image) Image<double>;
%template(Imageint) Image<int>;
%template(Imagedouble) Image<double>;
```

in the interface file.  However, swig then complains about Image being redefined.

What is the best way to make an alias such that Image and Imagedouble both refer to C++ `Image<double>`?   Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

-Josh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case this helps someone in the future, the way to do what is describe above is to add the following to the interface file:

```
%pythoncode %{
Image = Imagedouble
%}
```

I did not realize there was a way to write standard python code in the interface file.

Comment: What I was going to suggest, not being familiar with swig, was doing the name assignment in Python. So it's nice that swig makes it easy to do just that.

Comment: Thank you for writing the answer to your own question.  I too have templates like Foo<FloatingPointType> and wanted Foo<double> to be the default usable by the name 'Foo' within Python.